# Angle between two curves first fundamental form and chain rule

Tags: differential-geometry, chain-rule

[image]
Here $r_1$ is in terms of $u_1$ and $r_2$ in terms of $u_2$, how can they write $E$ when we have dot product of $r_1$ with respect to $u_1$ and $r_2$ with respect to $u_2$. We can write $E$ only when they are the same right?

Comment: Perhaps reading an old-fashioned text is confusing you more than it is worth. Consider reading a more modern text (mine is free and is available with one click in my profile). What is here is inconsistent, since $u_i$, $v_i$ were given as functions of $t$, not $s_i$.  Just write down the tangent vectors $(u_1'(t),v_1'(t))$ and $(u_2'(t),v_2'(t))$ (assuming that $P=(u_1(t),v_1(t))=(u_2(t),v_2(t))$ so that you're computing $E,F,G$ at the single point $P$ (this is what it means for the two curves to intersect at $P$).

Comment: @Ted Shifrin, thank you I shall check your text. So because of the common intersection point ${r_1}_{u_1}$ and ${r_2}_{u_2}$ coincide and have the same value at $P$?

Comment: Yes! They should have stated that explicitly. Not sure you typed the right thing here, though. No derivatives.

Comment: What I intended to type is, the tangent vectors are $\dot {r_1}=r_u1{\dot u1}+r_v1{\dot v1}$ and $\dot {r_2}=r_u2{\dot u1}+r_v2{\dot v1}$ and here because of the common point $r_u1$ and $r_u2$ are the same and the dot product gives $E$ of the fundamental form. Am I right?

Comment: No, you're still confused. Reread what I wrote several comments up. There are no derivatives when you figure out what point you're at.

Comment: Guess I’m really confused. This is really bothering for more than a day. No derivatives? But we are finding partial derivative using chain rule right?

Comment: Guess I’m too stupid to understand

Comment: Sorry for wasting your precious time.